# Translation of a bounded uniformly continuous function is fixed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

> if $f$ is a bounded uniformly continuous real-valued function on $\Bbb R$, then for all $T>0$, there is a sequence $a_n$ converging to infinity that $f(x+a_n)$ converges on $[0,T]$

I am trying to prove this beautiful result which is saying the figure of the function is fixed on a interval under translation. But I have trouble constructing such $a_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proved it, I guess. By showing $\{f(x+a): a\in \Bbb R\}$ is equicontinuous and bounded. Therefore, I can apply Ascoli on $C[0,T]$